# Add Dollar to numeric values without converting to characters

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with numerical values. Is there a way to add $ sign without converting to character. Right now when I add $ sign, the numerical values are converted to character

```
Col A   Col B
A        12
B        14
C        15
```

Expected output

```
Col A   Col B
A        $ 12
B        $ 14
C        $ 15
```

Please note `class(df$ColB)` should be numeric

Comment: Why don't you simply rename the column as something like `Col B [USD]`?!

Comment: @AlexB I agree. But dollar sign is required so that it can displayed on graphs . I’m using ramcharts for this barplot.

Comment: If the question is *"Is there a way..."* then the answer is *"no, there isn't"*.

Comment: To display dollar signs, `scales::dollar(df$ColB)`. Package `scales` has several formating functions used in graphic commands or with `ggplot`.

Comment: `class(scales::dollar(c(100, 20)))` but still a string...Even for barplots, you can label your axis and display the value there.

Comment: @AlexB Yes, I know. But if the problem is to plot something, then `scales` is very used. It keeps class `"numeric"` and formats for plots.